# How to integrate ionic2-rating plugin in alert ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, alert, rating

I am making a rating form where I am suppose to make rating stars but if I use alert then I am not able to make rating stars like empty and then fill by clicking .How to make it in alert

I have following html code

```
   <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
      </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
 </ion-header>
 <ion-content>
   <ion-card padding>
     <rating [(ngModel)]="rate" max="5" emptyStarIconName="star-outline"  
   halfStarIconName="star-half"     starIconName="star"  nullable="false"  
  (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)">
  </rating>
  <h2>{{rate}}</h2>
 </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

and this is its scss

```
 ul {
  padding: 10px;
  &.rating li {
    padding: 5px 10px !important;
    background: none;
    color: #ffb400;
    ion-icon {
      font-size: 40px;
    }
  }
  }
```

This working fine but it is working in card I want a pop up like alert and I dont know how to integrate it in alert.
Secondly I have tried to make alert itself with stars as buttons but its not working the way I wanted,I need help

Comment: Can you show your controller with the alert ?

Comment: I haven't use alert yet!

Comment: You need to search for ionic modals.

Answer (score 0):

Hi put above css under src\theme\variables.scss

Comment: It's working fine with ion-cards,I want to make alert